# How to create a control that has a collection

Tags: c#, custom-controls

OK, let me be more specific. I know how to create a control with a collection property, but what I've never done is written one that has markup associated with it.

What I want to know is, given an control defined like this ...

```
public class MyControl 
{
    public List<MySubItems> Items {get; set;}
}
```

What do I have to do to be able to create markup, like this...

```
<MyStuff:MyControl runat="server" ID="MyControl1">
  <Items>
    <MySubItem ... />
    <MySubItem ... />
  </Items>
</MyStuff:MyControl>
```

Apologies if this seems a bit of a noddy question, but I've never done this before.

-- 
Stuart

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.Net custom control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to apply the [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) along with [PersistenceModeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistencemodeattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on your property. Assuming it's a ASP.NET control.

This is what it would look like -

```
public class MyControl:WebControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public List<MySubItems> Items {get; set;}
}
```

See [MSDN: Web Control Collection Property Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for a detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for Templated controls http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx

Comment: Actually, I wasn't but thanks for the pointer anyway as I've found this useful for something else!